# Sair do loop repentinamente

Tags: javascript, jquery

Imaginemos o seguinte código:

```
function FazAlgoTrabalhoso(parametro1, parametro2, parametro3){
//Algo trabalhoso aqui
}

var i;
for(i=0;i<=coisas.length;i++){
  //"coisas" é um array já preenchido
  FazAlgoTrabalhoso(coisas[i].algo1, coisas[i].algo2, coisas[i].algo3);
}

$( "#botao_para_cancelar" ).click(function() {
  //Algo para cancelar...
});
```

- Digamos que o array "coisas" tenha 100 posições, logo, o loop for vai
  rodar 100 vezes, ou seja, fará "algo trabalhoso" 100 vezes.
- Consideremos também que "FazAlgoTrabalhoso" demora uns 5 segundos
  para se executar completamente.

**Minha dúvida é:** Como gerenciar o cancelamento de "FazAlgoTrabalhoso"? Por exemplo, se ele já rodou 50 vezes, como cancelar as execuções subsequentes através de um botão? Não obtive sucesso em minhas tentativas e ele sempre acaba rodando o loop todo....

Comment: if ( condicao ) return

Comment: Creio que o problema esteja no loop for. Mesmo que tenha um return dentro da função, o for já "ordenou" as 100 execuções e ele acaba passando...

Answer (score 2):

O seu maior problema é que...

```
var i;
for(i=0;i<=coisas.length;i++){
  FazAlgoTrabalhoso(coisas[i].algo1, coisas[i].algo2, coisas[i].algo3);
}
```

...é um processo *síncrono*, o que significa que o JavaScript não irá parar para verificar se um evento foi disparado, como o clicar de de um botão.

Você precisa converter essa função para operar de modo assíncrono:

```
function FazAlgoTrabalhosoAsync(x) {
  if (!x) x = 0;

  FazAlgoTrabalhoso(coisas[i].algo1, coisas[i].algo2, coisas[i].algo3);

  if (x < coisas.length) 
      setTimeout(function() {FazAlgoTrabalhosoAsync(x + 1);}, 1);
}

FazAlgoTrabalhosoAsync();
```

`setTimeout()` faz com que a função seja chamada no futuro. Nesse meio tempo, eventos podem ser interceptados, e uma flag para interrupção marcada como *true*:

```
var tenhoQueParar = false;

$( "#botao_para_cancelar" ).click(function() {
  tenhoQueParar = true;
});

function FazAlgoTrabalhosoAsync(x) {
  if (!x) x = 0;

  FazAlgoTrabalhoso(coisas[i].algo1, coisas[i].algo2, coisas[i].algo3);

  if ((x < coisas.length) && !tenhoQueParar) 
      setTimeout(function() {FazAlgoTrabalhosoAsync(x + 1);}, 1);
}

FazAlgoTrabalhosoAsync();
```

Comment: Hmm parece que é aí que estou errando... Logo mais, vou testar... Só uma dúvida: Me corrija se eu estiver errado, mas creio que onde você diz "Síncrono" seria "Assíncrono" e vice-versa, não? Pois se minha função fosse assíncrona, ou seja, esperasse o resultado anterior para continuar, creio que ela funcionaria... Me corrija se estou equivocado. Obrigado pela ótima resposta :)

Comment: Acredito que os termos estejam corretos, @PedroAntônio - uma função assíncrona está fora de sincronia, ou seja, não espera.

Comment: Sim, @OnoSendai, é que você disse que minha função é síncrona... e a meu ver, ela não está esperando o resultado anterior...

Comment: @PedroAntônio Nop, eu disse que o *processo* é síncrono. Entre o laço fornecido pelo `for` e as chamadas sequenciais da função `FazAlgoTrabalhoso` não existe espaço para outros eventos acontecerem. As chamadas sequenciais ocorrem de maneira síncrona, nesse caso.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
    function FazAlgoTrabalhoso(parametro1, parametro2, parametro3){
    //Algo trabalhoso aqui

    var timer = window.setInterval(function(){
    var pagina = $$('.page').data('page');
    console.log("Estou na página: "+pagina);
    if(pagina != 'preview'){
        //Rotina de cancelamento...

        console.log('Abortado');
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
 },1000);
}
```

Ou seja, mudei o escopo. Ao invés de cancelar no clique de um botão, consegui monitorar quando o usuário deixa a página. Nisso, cancelo o processo.

Answer (score -1):

Para sair do loop é so adicionar o break

```
var cancelar = false;
function FazAlgoTrabalhoso(parametro1, parametro2, parametro3){
//Algo trabalhoso aqui
}

var i;
for(i=0;i<=coisas.length;i++){
  //"coisas" é um array já preenchido
  FazAlgoTrabalhoso(coisas[i].algo1, coisas[i].algo2, coisas[i].algo3);
  if (cancelar){
      break;
  }
}

$( "#botao_para_cancelar" ).click(function() {
  cancelar = true;
});
```

Comment: Mas no meu caso, a interrupção do loop teria que ser através do clique em um botão - que poderia ocorrer a qualquer momento, ou seja, o loop provavelmente já se percorreu todo....

Comment: Editei a pergunta com o "botão cancelador"

Comment: troque a variavel, count = 0; por cancelar = false; aonde quando você der um clique no botão cancelar ele coloque cancelar = true;